# Checkboxes displaying indexes instead of text

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am new to android, currently in my second year in I.t..

I'm working on a grocery list app project, where I display a list of groceries for the user to select and to display them on the next screen (Screen 2).

The problem I am having, is, when I click the Show List button, it displays the indexes of the selected checkboxes instead of the text displayed... I have tried using a ListActivity to display an array in a CheckedTextView but that didn't work out either (checkboxes were not checking when selected).

I would really appreciate some help on how to display the selected text instead of the checkboxes selected indexes and would like to know where I am going wrong.

Below is my Java and XML code for the 2 screens..

Java Coding - Screen 1

```
package com.allmycode.lists;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  static CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[18];

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LinearLayout layout = 
    (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  checkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(this);
  layout.addView(checkBoxes[i]);
}
checkBoxes[0].setText("Baking Ingredients");
checkBoxes[1].setText("Beverages");
checkBoxes[2].setText("Canned Foods");
checkBoxes[3].setText("Cereal");
checkBoxes[4].setText("Dairy");
checkBoxes[5].setText("Detergents");
checkBoxes[6].setText("Frozen Vegetables");
checkBoxes[7].setText("Fruit");
checkBoxes[8].setText("Broad Beans");
checkBoxes[9].setText("Herbs");
checkBoxes[10].setText("Legumes");
checkBoxes[11].setText("Meat");
checkBoxes[12].setText("Pasta");
checkBoxes[13].setText("Pet Food");
checkBoxes[14].setText("Rice");
checkBoxes[15].setText("Snacks");
checkBoxes[16].setText("Toiletries");
checkBoxes[17].setText("Vegetables");
}

  public void onShowListClick(View view) {
   Intent intent =
    new Intent(this, MyListActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

XML Coding - Screen 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android=

  "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onShowListClick"
    android:text="@string/show_list" >
</Button>
```

Java Coding - Screen 2

```
package com.allmycode.lists;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ArrayList<Integer> listItems =
    new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  if (MainActivity.checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
      listItems.add(i);
  }
}

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter <Integer> (this,
    R.layout.my_list_layout, listItems));
}
}
```

XML Coding - Screen 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android=
  "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/identView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Comment: before adding view setText to checkBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only setting the indexes, so it makes sense that's what's happening:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listItems = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // <-- List of Integers

for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  if (MainActivity.checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
      listItems.add(i); // <-- You're adding an integer to the List
  }
}
```

Try this instead:

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>(); // <-- List of Strings

for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  if (MainActivity.checkBoxes[i].isChecked()) {
      listItems.add(MainActivity.checkBoxes[i].getText()); // Set it to the text of the Checkbox, not the integer index in the loop
  }
}

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, R.layout.my_list_layout, listItems));
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're not an Android programmer - see my answer.

Comment: Nowhere did I say trying to access the CheckBoxes via a reference to the first Activity was a good idea, however he has a static reference to it which would work regardless of your theory of "breaking the Activity model." I definitely agree that passing the data via the Intent is the best approach, but to suggest his method of doing it is wrong is pretty wrong in and of itself. And my sole intention here was to show why he was displaying the indexes, as opposed to the actual text, and not actually critique every line of code.

Comment: So what happens if his MainActivity is destroyed and his MyListActivity is possibly holding a reference to his static array of checkboxes?...That'll be a memory leak. I know his code doesn't show holding a reference but my point is that it is wrong to assume accessing fields or methods in an `Activity` will work at any given time regardless of whether or not they are static. An Activity should be modular and no assumption to state of fields or methods should be made. Data should be passed or persisted and not accessed directly.

Comment: I agree with every last thing you wrote (minus the SharedPreferences suggestion for passing List data between Activities), but it still has nothing to do with his original question and your initial insult was a bit immature.

Comment: I agree `SharedPreferences` would be 'clunky' but a CSV or JSON string could be used. Personally I'd probably use a 'helper' class as even passing the states of the checkboxes by Intent extras wouldn't be much more efficient than even `SharedPreferences`. As for my 'insult', it wasn't meant to be and I apologise if you took it that way. If you look at the question it has a Java tag and I often see answers from Java programmers to Android questions but those programmers don't program for Android and don't understand the Activity life-cycle.

Comment: Well then I apologize for taking it incorrectly and I definitely agree with those suggestions. I do actually have a question for you, though: "So what happens if his MainActivity is destroyed and his MyListActivity is possibly holding a reference to his static array of checkboxes?" -- isn't it still possible for the static reference to exist even when the Activity itself has been destroyed? Assuming there are other Activities still running and the Application, itself, hasn't been killed, the reference should 'generally' persist (assuming the OS didn't need to destroy them), no?

Comment: In theory having a reference to something like a `static final` primitive data type isn't going to pose a problem but in the case of an array of objects they're effectively going to be 'orphaned' if the `Activity` is destroyed and anything holding a reference will prevent the GC from cleaning up. A worst case scenario with a programmer using a static object, array of objects or a method in an Activity is that relevant data hasn't been set, objects haven't been initialised etc etc. In other words unknown state and the potential for NPEs.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Guardanis is technically correct if you were working with a regular Java class. The Android `Activity` class is NOT a regular Java class however.

Never try to access fields or methods in one `Activity` from any other app component. In some cases it *might* work but that approach breaks the `Activity` model and if you continue along that line, i.e., assuming an `Activity` is just a regular Java class, at some point your app will crash and burn.

The correct way to do what you are doing is to work out which checkboxes are checked using code in your MainActivity BEFORE you start MyListActivity. You'd then need to pass that information to MyListActivity either as `Intent` extras or by saving the data in `SharedPreferences` or using some other way of sharing the data.

Comment: You do realize it's a static reference, and he's not actually accessing an instance version of the CheckBox list, right? Albeit, if he were doing that, I would agree with you. And suggesting that he use SharedPreferences for passing selected List data makes me question your answer as well...